# packaging air application with air runtime in one installer - windows .exe

Tags: windows, air, installation, package, exe

I've been approved to distribute the adobe air run time. I've been able to a packaged .dmg file without any problems, now I'm trying to create a package of my application with the runtime for windows.

I've followed the same [instructions](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/air/redist/WS485a42d56cd19641-70d979a8124ef20a34b-8000.html) and the windows installer (MyApp 2.0 Installer.exe) is working properly when I double click it form the installer directory that I created.

Now I'm trying to package everything from that directory into one .exe file. I've tried using the standard windows Iexpress, but it doesn't seem to work properly.

I'm just wondering how I should go about creating the final .exe file.

Answer (score 1):

It's easy enough, but you need a [license from Adobe to be able to distribute Air with your application](http://www.adobe.com/products/air/runtime_distribution1.html).  Personally, I'm not a fan of distributing Air in the installer because of the extra filesize it adds.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you can create a native `.exe` installer:

### Install the SDK:

1. If you haven't already done so, download the [AIR SDK](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/air/air-sdk-download.html) and extract it to `C:\AIR`
2. Hit <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>, and type `control.exe sysdm.cpl,System,3` - press <kbd>OK</kbd>
3. Click <kbd>Environment Variables...</kbd>
4. In the lower pane (*System variables*), find *Path* and click <kbd>Edit...</kbd>
5. On the end, add `;C:\AIR` and hit <kbd>OK</kbd> all the way out

### Compile:

1. Open a Command Prompt window, and `cd` to the location of your `.air` file
2. Run this command:

```
adt -package -target native "Output file.exe" "Input file.air"
```

### N.B.:

> - You must use ADT on the same operating system as that of the native installer file you want to generate. So, to create an EXE file for Windows, run ADT on Windows. To create a DMG file for Mac OS, run ADT on Mac OS. To create a DEB or RPG file for Linux, run ADT from the AIR 2.6 SDK on Linux.

- Just as your `.air` file can be signed, your `.exe` file can be signed too
- For more information, see the [Packaging a desktop native installer](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/air/build/WS789ea67d3e73a8b22388411123785d839c-8000.html) article on Adobe's website